# C# Отображение номера итерации в label

Tags: c#

В цикле происходит копирование файлов. По скольку размеры файлов и их количество может быть большим, хотелось бы помимо прогресс бара так же выводить цифровое значение скопированных уже файлов. Моя попытка не увенчалась успехом: в лэйбле появляется число только по окончанию цикла.
`progress` — это и есть нужный лэйбл.

```
foreach (var k in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            string month = k.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM");

            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(dpath, month)))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dpath, month, k.Name)))
                    {
                        pBar.PerformStep();
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Copy(Path.Combine(spath, k.Name), Path.Combine(dpath, month, k.Name));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DirectoryInfo newdir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dpath, month));
                    File.Copy(Path.Combine(spath, k.Name), Path.Combine(dpath, month, k.Name));
                }      
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + e.ToString());
            }
            i += 1;
            progress.Text = i + " файлов из " + dir.GetFiles().Length + " отсортировано";
            pBar.PerformStep();
        }
        bDone.Visible = true;   
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы делаете всю работу в потоке UI. Поэтому пока идет копирование файла - вы даже отрисовать окно не можете.

Тут вам могут помочь асинхронные методы. Проще всего сделать следующим образом.

Первое. Метод, в котором это все будет происходить, объявляем асинхронным:

```
async void CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir) {
    // ...
}
```

или

```
async Task CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir) {
    // ...
}
```

Второе. "Долгие" вызовы оборачиваем в задачу, чтобы выполнить в фоновом потоке:

```
await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(Path.Combine(spath, k.Name), Path.Combine(dpath, month, k.Name)));
```

Этого уже достаточно, чтобы поток UI не "вешался" и успевал отрисовать вашу метку.

---

Тем не менее, способ выше также не идеален - осталась еще куча вызовов, которые могут заблокировать поток. Оборачивать их все в `Task.Run` - глупо и неудобно. Поэтому надо вынести индикацию прогресса из алгоритма, что позволит выполнять его в фоне целиком.

Для уведомления UI о прогрессе из фонового потока начиная с .NET 4.5 существует удобный инструмент - [`Progress<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Использовать его можно так:

```
async void CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir) {
  var len = await Task.Run(() => dir.GetFiles().Length);

  var p = new Progress<int>(i => {
    progress.Text = i + " файлов из " + len + " отсортировано";
    pBar.PerformStep();
  });

  await Task.Run(() => RealCopyFiles(dir, p));
  bDone.Visible = true;
}

void RealCopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, IProgress<int> progress) {
  var i = 0;
  foreach (var k in dir.GetFiles()) {
    string month = k.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM");

    //...

    i += 1;
    progress.Report(i);
  }
}
```